# PHP: Как в curl запросе получить http-заголовок ответа сервера, если api просто не работает?

Tags: php, сервер, http, curl, http-заголовки

уважаемые специалисты!

Делаю запрос в api одного сервиса. Если api упала и сервер недоступен, то в $ch ничего не будет, хотя при обычной работе api, если введены, допустим, неверные учетные данные, то придет ошибка с кодом. Как получить при curl-запросе заголовки со статусами ответа, если api технически недоступен (ошибка 500) или по другой причине ничего не возвращает. Пробовал добавлять curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); но запрос перестает из-за этого работать и не возвращает не только http-заголовки, но и результат успешного запроса (без этого получаю json структуру). Пробовал также

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
print_r($httpcode);

на этот раз код приходит, но такой же, как в json структуре от самого api. Допустим, если в ней код 0 - успешный запрос, то и в $httpcode будет то же... Подозреваю, что в случае, если api будет недоступен, там не будет ничего... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки получить http-заголовки со статусами ошибок в ответе при curl запросе?

```
$data = array("user_name" => $this->log, "user_pass" => $this->pass);
        $ch = curl_init("$url");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, true);

return json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В curl можно получить [информацию по заголовкам](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-getinfo.php):

```
if (!curl_errno($ch)) {
  switch ($http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)) {
    case 200:  # OK
      break;
    default:
      echo 'Неожиданный код HTTP: ', $http_code, "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, что уделили время!